# How to generate a (boolean) formula from an Excel table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As an example we have the table below.

| condition_A | condition_b | condition_c | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| false | false | false | true |
| false | false | true | true |
| false | true | false | true |
| false | true | true | true |
| true | false | false | false |
| true | false | true | false |
| true | true | false | true |
| true | true | true | false |

Can excel generate a boolean formula on what `result` entry is per row, taking into account the values of the other corresponding columns?

eg. the formula is
`result = !condition_A OR (sth_else)`

Comment: `=IF(A1=FALSE,TRUE,IF(AND(B1=TRUE,C1=FALSE),TRUE,FALSE))`.

Comment: @BigBen Here's one flavor: `=(NOT(A2)+AND(B2,NOT(C2)))>0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my query. A piece of free software that can do this is called "Logic Friday", it can generate and even simplify boolean expressions from truth tables.

Answer (score 1):

Using logical formulas. Your logic on `(sth_else)` is unclear, but a guess:

```
=OR(NOT(A2),AND(B2,NOT(C2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly. I was too lazy to put it in a worksheet. When I did, it got even worse (OP's comments).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But apparently my question was not clear; perchance not phrased properly. I asked "Can excel generate a boolean formula on what result entry is per row, taking into account the values of the other corresponding columns?" In other words "Can Excel Generate a formula?" so that "I don't have to"? Am I understood?

Comment: No I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. You (the end user) dictate the logic, not the other way around. There are potentially many formulas that could lead to the result column.